# how to extract date from JSON data type column in Postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a column `open_houses` that's JSON data type and it looks like this:

```
open_houses
[{"Date": "2017-08-13", "ToTime": "4:00PM", "FromTime": "2:00PM"}]
[{"Date": "2017-08-12", "ToTime": "3:00PM", "FromTime": "1:00PM"}]
[{"Date": "2017-08-12", "ToTime": "4:00PM", "FromTime": "2:00PM"}]
[{"Date": "2017-08-13", "ToTime": "3:00PM", "FromTime": "1:00PM"}]
```

When I try to extract 'Date' from this column I get an error -

```
SELECT ...
FROM   prod.vw_listing
WHERE  ...
       ...
       AND open_houses[1] -> 'Date'::DATE >= current_date;
```

Error:

```
cannot subscript type jsonb because it is not an array
```

Answer (score 8):

Use the `->` operand to get a json array element:

```
with vw_listing (open_houses) as ( values 
    ('[{"Date": "2017-08-13", "ToTime": "4:00PM", "FromTime": "2:00PM"}]'::jsonb),
    ('[{"Date": "2017-08-12", "ToTime": "3:00PM", "FromTime": "1:00PM"}]'),
    ('[{"Date": "2017-08-12", "ToTime": "4:00PM", "FromTime": "2:00PM"}]'),
    ('[{"Date": "2017-08-13", "ToTime": "3:00PM", "FromTime": "1:00PM"}]')
)
select (open_houses -> 0 ->> 'Date')::date
from vw_listing
;
    date    
------------
 2017-08-13
 2017-08-12
 2017-08-12
 2017-08-13
```

Answer (score 5):

I was able to resolve this by doing this:

```
SELECT ...

FROM   prod.vw_listing
WHERE  ...
       AND (open_houses -> 0 ->> 'Date')::date>= current_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use this select:

```
select (open_houses#>> '{0, Date}')::date
```

It is equeal to selecting element like `open_houses[0]['Date']`